# Winform Design Architecture

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

I making a winform game which contain PictureBoxes as views.

When i started to get confused about "where to put things around" (especially in the case that i needed to make some objects make the picturebox222 refresh and activate by that its painting event)

Then i heard of architecture patterns... the MVC, MVP, MVVM
which of those patterns can help me in my task? and why?
I'll also be glad to get advise of a good place to learn about the pattern i need.

Thanks,
Gal

Comment: "which of those patterns can help me in my task?" What task?  Writing a program?  Any of them, none of them, etc.  It depends on a lot more than "where to put things around."  As for places to learn, I recommend tutorials and books on the subject in general.  But there's nothing specific in the question to lead to a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model View Presenter is a pattern you can use. MVC is for web applications, MVVM for WPF apps.
A good starting point for learning MVP is [WinForms Model View Presenter @ codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14660/WinForms-Model-View-Presenter) and [MSDN MVP](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=model%20view%20presenter).
A lot of the articles and tutorials about MVP deal with ASP.NET Webforms but can easily transfered to WinForms since they have a lot in common.

But when developing a game you should consider a more appropiate platform like [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx).

Comment: -1 MVC is used in a lot more than web applications. It's been around a lot longer than we've had the internet we know and love. I think you're confusing MVC with ASP.Net MVC, which is a web framework based off of the MVC design pattern.

Comment: Don't tell me that I confuse things I don't confuse. Writing a WinForms app (thats the subject) with MVC as pattern is a pretty bad idea since it doesn't match. When it comes to .NET MVC is mostly used for web apps base on ASP.NET MVC, that was my intention indeed. It doesn't make sense to start a monologue about the usage of MVC in Smalltalk or JS when aswering a question on SO, therefore I'm not doing it. If you can't provide anything useful stop down voting.

Comment: I'm trying to provide accurate information, not knock your answer. That's the point of SO. You made a sweeping generalization without explaining yourself, thus the down vote.